# Does `CD/DVD Creator` verify an optical disk after writing to it?

Tags: gnome, nautilus, dvd, burning, brasero

Does `CD/DVD Creator` verify an optical disk after writing to it? In other words, is the data read back and compared to the original?

**Edit: The OS is Ubuntu 12.04.**

Screenshot of the application 
[image: Screenshot of the application]

Screenshot of the About window of the application.
[image: Screenshot of the About window of the application]

Comment: What is the name of the application? How do you open it from terminal?

Comment: The application is `CD/DVD Creator`. It is invoked when a blank DVD is inserted into Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: What OS are you running? Try to open it from terminal and tell us what command do you use, otherwise take a screenshoot on the *about* window.

Comment: I don't know how to open it from terminal. It opens automatically in Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: one possibility could be [`nautilus-cd-burner`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus-cd-burner), but it was last supported for Lucid 10.04, so probably not... It looks like you have [previously found this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/186065/how-to-burn-cd-with-the-cd-dvd-creator#comment604531_186067) anyway... is `nautilus-cd-burner` installed, or another disc-burning front-end package that begins with `nautilus*`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To provide an answer to the question "Does `CD/DVD Creator` verify an optical disk after writing to it?"

**Yes it does**, I have just verified this myself.
In Ubuntu 12.04 and newer it is a Brasero plugin called "CD/DVD Creator Folder" that is providing this functionality to Nautilus.
When you click the "Write to disc" button in Nautilus (as in the first screenshot) it launches a Brasero dialog.
During the burn you should see a finalising write message, then afterwards verifying checksum message (under the progress bar).

Brasero by default verifies file an disk integrity.

[image: Default Brasero plugins, showing checksum plugins enabled by default]

Answer (score 3):

CD/DVD Creator is an awkward and confusing application to use, and you should switch to Brasero which automatically verifies an optical disk after writing to it and gives you a notification when it is done verifying the disk so that you can eject it.  Brasero is installed by default in Ubuntu 12.04.

The following screenshots provide a visual explanation of the preceding paragraph. In the first screenshot CD/DVD Creator was selected from the dialog box that appeared after inserting a blank CD, and I dragged in an iso file that I wanted to burn to a CD.

[image]

There is no tab or button to select **Burn image** even though the file to be burned is an iso image file. There is no button to select the disc burning speed.

In the next screenshot a blank CD was inserted and Brasero was opened by clicking on the Brasero icon in the Dash. Under the *Create a new project:* heading **Burn image** is selected.

[image]

The iso image file is added.

[image]

The *Properties* button was clicked to open the Properties window. In the **Burning speed** dropdown menu the slowest burning speed is selected for the best quality.

[image]

The disc integrity is checked after it is burnt.

[image]

These screenshots are from the built-in Brasero Disc Burner application with no changes in the settings except for selecting the slowest burning speed for burning the iso image to the CD.

Answer (score 0):

Like [Wilf](https://askubuntu.com/users/178596/wilf) says:

> This CD/DVD Creator tool could be nautilus-cd-burner [in launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus-cd-burner) and in [ubuntu packages](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/nautilus-cd-burner).

But it was last supported for Lucid 10.04 and it doesn't seem supported in newer versions of Ubuntu - you're using Ubuntu 12.04. It seems it has become obsolete.

As an alternative, you can also try K3B `sudo apt-get install k3b`

> K3b is a full-featured CD/DVD/Blu-ray burning and ripping application.
>   It supports a variety of project types as well as copying of optical media, burning of different types of images, and ripping Audio CDs, Video CDs, and Video DVDs.
>   Its convenient user interface is targeted at all audiences, trying to be as simple as possible for novice users while also providing all features an advanced user might need.

[image]

Comment: The OP is asking "Does `CD/DVD Creator` verify an optical disk after writing to it?" not asking for alternatives.